# Is there an elegant way in rails to take a string and wrap all internal words in a specified character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I'm making a search algorithm and would like to wrap all words in the search query in asterisks to help with partial matching. I'd also like to only wrap single words, while ignoring quotes. An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
'test test test' test2 test2 => 'test test test' *test2* *test2*
"test test test" test2 test2 => "test test test" *test2* *test2*
```

I have an algorithm that does this but it is really ugly

```
split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)/).map{|x| ["'", '"'].include?(x[0]) ? x+' ' : '*'+x+'* '}.join
```

Is there a more elegant railsian way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This will work unless there are spaces between the quotes and the word within quotes, so I'm unsure if that is acceptable for you or not:

```
str = "'test test' test test 'test'"
str.split(' ').map { |w| has_quotes?(w) ? w : "*#{w}*" }.join(' ')

def has_quotes?(w)
  w.include?('"') || w.include?("'")
end
```

This will output:

```
"'test test' *test* *test* 'test'"
```